# How do I save separate appointments in the richtextbox with the same date?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, appointment

Is there any way to save each row in the RichTextBox or using another method, in a row in access/mdb?
I choose the date I fill RichTextBox with the appointments, so when I click the Save button it sends separate appointments with the same date to access/mdb!

[Exemple, What I wanted, and how it happens!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roXmz.png)

Comment: Do you really need a RichTextBox to present your data or a DataGridView would do?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a database with a table with TODOs:

```
class Todo
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime DueDate {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

You also have a repository class, that connects to the database, and where you can fetch Todos and save new Todos, and maybe do other thing like Update a Todo.

Something like this:

```
class Repository
{
    public int Add(Todo todo) {...}

    public Todo Find(int Id) {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Todo> FetchAll() {...}
    public IEnumerable<Todo> FetchBetweenDates {DateTime start, Datetime finish) {...}
}
```

You might not have all functions, or maybe you have more than these. The important one is the Add method. Return value: id of the Added Todo

You also have a multiline RichTextBox, where every line contains the description of one Todo that you want to add.

Finally you have some control on your form that makes it possible to select a DueDate for all the TODO Descriptions in the RichTextBox.

```
private DateTime DueDate => DataTime.Parse(this.textBoxDueDate.Text);
// or maybe you have a DateTimePicker?

private void AddToRepository(DateTime dueDate, IEnumerable<string> todoDescriptions)
{
    Repository repository = new Repository(...);
    foreach (string todoDescription in totoDescriptions)
    {
        long todoId = repository.Add(new Todo
        {
            DueDate = dueDate,
            Description = todoDescription,
        });
        // what to do with the returned id?
    }
}
```

Now all you need is a method that reads the Descriptions:

```
IEnumerable<string> ReadTodoDescriptions()
{
    return this.TodoRichTextBox.Lines;
}
```

Now put this all together, for instance if a menu item is selected:

```
private void OnMenuItem_Save_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    this.AddToRepository(this.DueDate, this.ReadToDoDescriptions());
}
```